claude completion API does not have logprobs
I'm migrating my application from OpenAI API to Claude API. One feature I heavily rely on is logprobs parameter, which returns token probabilities and top tokens for each position in the generated text. However Claude doesn't offer this functionality directly.
With OpenAI, I could do:
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-4o",
  messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}
  ],
  logprobs=True,
  top_logprobs=2
)


Is there a workaround here?
